# Intent localisation not working on Shortcut app but ok on iOS settings

Tags: ios, swift, localization, siri, sirishortcuts

I have an app with some Siri Intents. The Intents file definition is localized, it works well on the iOS settings however the Shortcut app doesn't take localisation into account and keep the string inside the Intent definition file from Base localisation folder.

There is two topic on this on apple forum but no answer so far.

Any ideas?

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/110797

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108609

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/113161

Thanks in advance